# ANTLR Parsing - Ignoring comments on last line of input

Tags: antlr, antlr3

I'm using Antlr 3.2 and I'm having trouble writing a grammar to ignore comment lines. Specifically, I'm getting an error if a comment line is the last line of the input with no newline after it.

My input is effectively assembly language, where comments start anywhere on the line with a semi-colon, and go to end of line. Everything else is parsed as commands.

A cutdown version of my grammar that exhibits the problem is:

```
grammar Test;

options {
    language = Java;
    output = AST;
    ASTLabelType = CommonTree;
}

@header {
    package test;
}

@lexer::header {
    package test;
}

rule
    :   instruction+ EOF!
    ;

instruction
    :   'SET' NEWLINE!*
    ;

COMMENT
    :   ';' .* NEWLINE+ { $channel=HIDDEN; }
    ;

NEWLINE
    :  '\r'? '\n'
    ;

WS
    :   (' ' | '\r' | '\n' | '\t' | '\f')+ { $channel = HIDDEN; }
    ;
```

If I use an input like:

```
; comment line 1 with blank line after it

SET ; comment after command
; comment line again
```

I get an error when parsing this saying `line 4:11 required (...)+ loop did not match anything at character '<EOF>'`.

If I add a newline to the last line of the input, it works fine as the newline is matched by the comment stripping, and the EOF matches at end of rule.

How can I better write this so it ignores comments on the final line but doesn't give an error? I don't want to append anything to the original input to hack it, is there a cleaner way to read comment lines? I've tried all kinds of combinations of NEWLINE|EOF but nothing gets rid of the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should do it:

```
COMMENT
    :   ';' ~('\r' | '\n')* { $channel=HIDDEN; }
    ;
```

And if you want a `COMMENT` to potentially have a line break at the end, do:

```
COMMENT
    :   ';' ~('\r' | '\n')* NEWLINE? { $channel=HIDDEN; }
    ;
```

However, the two rules `NEWLINE` and `WS`:

```
NEWLINE
    :  '\r'? '\n'
    ;

WS
    :   (' ' | '\r' | '\n' | '\t' | '\f')+ { $channel = HIDDEN; }
    ;
```

are dangerous: ANTLR works like this: it tries to match as much as possible, so the rule that matches the most "wins". If two (or more) rules match the same amount of characters, the one defined first "wins".

In other words, if the lexer sees input like `"\n"`, a `NEWLINE` is created. But if the lexer sees `" \n"` (a space followed by a `"\n"`), a `WS` token is created (and put on the `HIDDEN` channel).

I'm not sure if line breaks really *are* significant in your language (their not in any flavor of assembly language, AFAIK) so simply remove the `NEWLINE` rule. If the *are* significant, remove both the chars `\r` and `\n` from the `WS` rule.

Comment: This is good and gets rid of the error, however I have a follow up question. If this is true of the WS rule hiding the line breaks, why do i need one after the `instruction` to terminate that rule? If I put your change in and then remove NEWLINE* from `instruction`, it fails with `line 3:27 extraneous input '\n' expecting EOF` at the end of the comment. Which makes me confused over why the \n at the end of the comment on line 3 isn't being swallowed by the `WS` lexer rule.

Comment: No, sorry, I missed the `NEWLINE` rule and only saw the `WS` rule.

Comment: Thanks for your updated answer. I pieced it together from your initial answer, and then came back here to comment and found you'd updated! You're spot on that I had to remove the NEWLINE rule. They aren't significant in my case.